# Expressions that have redundancies that can be removed by manipulating the expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, soft-question

There are at least three identical questions on the subject, all with perfectly good answers, accepted ones as well. Since it is a very interesting question, far reaching while it does not appear like it, and no one, as far as I can see, has referred to the concept I want to talk about, I decided to open this question and answer it myself.

The question is as follows; Suppose we have defined a function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$, is this function equal to $1$?

People answered, correctly, that $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $x = 0$, and is of course not defined at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

So, the question becomes a little bit more interesting when we ask about the expression $\frac{x}{x}$, and not the function defined by this expression. By going through this route though, we gain more insight for the original question.

Suppose we take $x \neq 0$, and we are allowed to do manipulation involving the symbols $+, -, /, *, =, \neq$, numbers and variables, provided it is valid. In a more formal sense, we would say that we have a first order logical system, with said symbols, axioms for equality , functions ($ a = b \Rightarrow f(a) = f(b)$), and axioms of a field (since the real numbers form a field, this is reasonable). We would also need $a ^ {-1} = \frac{1}{a}$, but this is a technicality.

So in this context, we have that the proposition $\forall x, x \neq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{x} = 1$ is a theorem. This would mean that the functions $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}, x\neq 0$, and $g(x) = 1, x\neq 0$ are *extensionally equal*. They are *not* equal in the strongest sense possible, which is that they are *syntactically* equal, since only $1$ is syntactically equal to $1$, $2 - 1$ is not. We have to apply some form of reduction, in our case, applying the rules of the logical system (but different forms of reduction can be constructed here), to get there. Extensional equality means that when the expressions are reduced by some rules, for any argument, they provide the same result.

This whole story might seem like a redundancy, but it really is not. What if instead of $\frac{x}{x}$, we had a very complicated expression that could still be reduced to $1$?. It formalizes the concept that these expressions might *seem* equal, but require extra steps to be certain of the equality.

A stronger example of why extensional equality is important, comes up when trying to define polynomials with coefficients from a finite ring, for example integers *modulo 2*. If we define them with the extensional equality, we get a finite set, if we define them with the syntactic equality, we get an infinite set.

So the original question is an example that does not require a lot of background, but gives the opportunity to introduce extensional equality. The person asking the question should be notified of this, since answering just with "This is a removable discontinuity", does not answer the question that is hidden behind the scenes, namely that these expression *seem* equal, but are really not, in a sense.